# Installation error in RTI Connext Performance Test 1.1b: How to solve?

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to install the RTI Connext Performance Test from http://community.rti.com/kb/example-performance-test-rti-connext and I'm following the installation instructions. When I try to run the application with the following command:

`/opt/RTI/rtiperftest.1.1b/scripts/perftest_java -pub -noPrint -scan`

but I am getting an error that says "Error: Could not find or load main class com.rti.perftest.ddsimpl.PerfTestLauncher".

I checked and it does reside in /opt/RTI/rtiperftest.1.1b/perftest_java/com/rti/perftest/ddsimpl/PerfTestLauncher.java.

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

The version of the perftest application that is available on the RTI Community website is provided as source code.  You must build the application before you can run it.

To build the application you must have ant installed.  The steps are as follows:

export NDDSHOME=~/rti/ndds.5.1.0

cd perftest_java

ant -propertyfile ../resource/properties/dds_release.properties

To run the application you must have $NDDSHOME/lib/[jdkplatform] in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  For example:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/rti/ndds.5.1.0/lib/i86Linux2.6gcc4.4.5jdk:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

At that point, you should be able to run the performance test.